# How to delete an .exe file written in Python from within the .exe file?

Tags: python, exe, delete-file

I am trying to create a script which clones a github repository into the current directory and then deletes the script which called it.

The script is written in Python 3.7.4 and is compiled into an **.exe**.
I've tried using `os.remove(sys.argv[0])` which works before compiling but will not work for my end application.
I have also tried several other deletion methods however none of them worked at all, either with or without compiling into an **.exe**.

```py
import os

def function:
    # code

def main():
    function()
    os.remove(sys.argv[0])
```

I'm looking to have the **.exe** delete itself after running like the **.py** file does however I don't know the actual method to go around doing this.

Comment: Usually an executable file remains open by the operating system until the execution ends. In Linux you can unlink the file from a directory, so the file disappears from the files' tree, but does not get actually deleted until the process termination. I'm not sure if similar behavior is possible in Windows, though. AFAIK the file remains open (and write-protected) by the system during the process execution, so the program can not delete itself (but I may be wrong).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write a batch file to delete the Python file after execution but I am not sure if that is a good idea. It is definitely possible though.

**C:\test.py:**

```py
import os
os.startfile(r"C:\test.bat")
```

**C:\test.bat:**

```
TASKKILL /IM "process name" 
DEL "C:\test.py"
```

Comment: Even better - the `bat` file *can* delete itself as well