# Python - Delete a file through exe

Tags: python, exe, delete-file

I have written the following python code in the jupyter notebook with file name as `deletion.ipynb`:

```
import os
PATH=os.getcwd()
print("Current Working Directory is: ", PATH)
os.remove(PATH+"\Details.xlsx")
```

Now, I have created an executable file by first convert this `deletion.ipynb` file into `deletion.py` file using `!jupyter nbconvert --to script deletion.ipynb` and then convert this `deletion.py` file  into `.exe` by using `!pyinstaller deletion.py`. Now, an executable file is created in path `\dist\deletion\deletion.exe`.

When I try to run this executable file then console gets open and then closed suddenly without deleting the file `Details.xlsx`. I have already put `Details.xlsx` file in path `\dist\deletion` so that it should take the file from the current working directory where the executable is, But it is unable to delete the file.

Can anyone please help me how to delete a file by using an executable file which is created from python code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know windows much, but the current directory will be that from which you run the executable, not necessarily the location of the executable itself. Why don't you output `PATH` into a file in a known location to check that you have the correct path?

Comment: Sorry. I am not getting you. I am printing the path from where the executable is running. I have put `os.getcwd()` to detect the location of executable from where it is executed and put that file in that path. I have got one solution from here to delete file by making batch file from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58502457/how-to-delete-a-exe-file-written-in-python-from-within-the-exe-file but don't know why my code is not working.