# os.startfile() doesn't work after compiling python script with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I've made selfdestruct function that create a batch file that deletes the executable. It works when running the python file and the batch file opens normally. But after compiling it to an exe using pyinstaller it doesn't open.

I tried this

```
import os, sys
batchFilePath = 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\selfDelete.bat'
pathofscript = sys.argv[0]
batchCode = f'del /F /Q  {pathofscript}'
with open(batchFilePath, 'w') as f:
    f.write(batchCode)
    f.close()
os.startfile(batchFilePath)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete an .exe file written in Python from within the .exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58502457/how-to-delete-an-exe-file-written-in-python-from-within-the-exe-file)

Comment: Sorry to propose this duplicate target again, but I think it's really the same question, even if the answer did not work for you. (If I'm missing why it's different, please clarify your question.) New (better?) answers should be added to the other question so they are kept together in one place and can be found more easily. Note that duplicate questions are not removed, they will be kept as "sign post" to direct to the other question with all answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sys.executable` when targeting the executable. However your should note that when running the code as a python script `sys.executable` points to `python.exe`. So running your code as a python script would delete your python executable.

As such, I suggest testing to make sure that the code is being run from the compiled executable before executing the portion that actually runs the batch file. I have included an example of this below.

```
import os, sys, pathlib

batchFilePath = pathlib.Path.home() / "Desktop" / 'selfDelete.bat'

if pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.name.startswith("_MEI"):
    batchFilePath.write_text(f'del /F /Q  {sys.executable}')
    os.startfile(batchFilePath)
```